# jupyter console commands from bash script

Tags: bash, python-3.x, terminal, jupyter-console

I've been using jupyter notebooks for a little while and am trying to learn more about the jupyter console and bash scripting. I can't figure out how to get the most basic command to run using a bash script though:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "Testing jupyter console from bash script"
echo

jupyter console 
print('hi')     
exit
```

Here's what it looks like in my IDE (same output as terminal):

[image]

So is it possible to write a bash/jupyter console script or is there some other way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: `print('hi')` is not a valid Bash construct.  Try `echo hi` or `printf '%s\n' "hi"`.

Comment: after the `jupyter console` command it starts the console app. So I'm trying to run a print command from that console app.

Comment: Try `jupyter console <<< "print('hi')"` assuming jupyter reads from stdin.

Comment: doesn't seem to work